# CSharp Compiler Runtime error with ASP.NET Razor

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a new ASP.NET service.

Everything runs fine on my local machine. However, on the cluster I get the following error whenever I try to navigate to a page:

```
Missing compiler required member 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpArgumentInfo.Create'
```

The specific line throwing this error is the very beginning of my C# Razor view:

```
ViewBag.Title = "My Home Page";
```

I looked around StackOverflow, and found that others had solved a similar issue by referencing `Microsoft.CSharp` directly, but this has not solved my issue.

**Versions:**

- ASP.NET Core v1.1.0
- ASP.NET Core MVC v1.1.0
- .NET Framework v4.6.1

**My Controller:**

```
public sealed class MyController: Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger logger;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="MyController"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="logger">Dependency Injected logger</param>
    public MyController(ILogger<MyController> logger)
    {
        if (logger == null)
        {
            throw new System.ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
        }

        this.logger = logger;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the homepage
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>ASP.NET Razor page</returns>
    [ActionName("Index")]
    [Route("")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return this.View();
    }
}
```

**Start of my View (Index.cshtml):**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "My Home Page";
}
```

I had to add this to My Program.cs (in the `ConfigureServices` block) in order to get it working locally. I suspect this might be the issue, but unsure how to fix:

```
services.AddMvc().AddRazorOptions(options =>
{
    foreach (var assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
    {
        if (!assembly.IsDynamic && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(assembly.Location))
        {
            options.AdditionalCompilationReferences.Add(MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(assembly.Location));
        }
    }
});
```

Any suggestions for a fix much appreciated!

Comment: Are you loading views from another assembly?

Comment: No, the views are all within my normal project. I just couldn't get Razor to work locally without those entries in Program.cs